# ember.js + ember-simple-auth how can I load application models after authentication?

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm adding ember-simple-auth to handle authentication for an application I'm building. Currently in the ApplicationRoute I'm using a model to load sidebar content.

Some of the data is dependant on a user URL property which is returned with the auth token.

I'm refactoring my code to handle loading data for the authenticated user but I'm unsure where to put the model call to load the sidebar data.

I'm thinking it'd make sense to add an observer on the isAuthenticated property to trigger the model load or take my current routes and wrap them in a resource which is responsible for loading the model?

**Application Route**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin,
{
    model: function()
    {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash(
        {
            collections: Ember.$.getJSON(this.session.get('user.url') + '/collection'),

            libraries: Ember.$.getJSON(ENV.api + '/library')
        });
    },


    setupController: function(controller, model)
    {
        controller.set('libraries', model.libraries);

        controller.set('collections', model.collections);
    }
});
```

**Route Mapping**

```
App.Router.map(function()
{
    this.route('login');

    // Authenticated Routes

    this.route('my-account');

    this.route('collection', { path: '/collection/:id' });

    this.route('item.new', { path: '/item/new' });

    this.route('item.edit', { path: '/item/:id' });

    this.route('library', { path: '/:slug' });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this.get('session.user_email')` in routes to get the authenticated user's email, and then use that to fetch the user data from the server.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar and just piping in the user ID into the response packet.

Answer (score 0):

The `ApplicationRouteMixin` defines the [`sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` action](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-ApplicationRouteMixin-sessionAuthenticationSucceeded) that is invoked whenever the session state changes from not authenticated to authenticated. You can also listen to the session's [`sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` event](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-Session-sessionAuthenticationSucceeded)